# Spring Boot Kafka Connection Problem for bitnamiKafka docker service

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka

There is no problem everything is ok on the terminals; i can send message via producer and receive it on consumer. But am not able to get same result via KafkaProducer java.

```
  kafka:

    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - '9093:9093'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  zookeeper:
      image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
      ports:
        - "2181:2181"
      environment:
        - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes

networks:
  microservicesnet:
    driver: bridge
```

**Java code for KafkaProducer**

```
    public  Producer<String, String> setUpKafkaPropoerties() {
                   Properties properties = new Properties();
                //Update the IP adress of Kafka server here//

                properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9093");
                properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
                  StringSerializer.class);
                properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
                  StringSerializer.class);

                properties.put("acks", "all");
                properties.put("retries", 0);
                properties.put("linger.ms", 0);
                properties.put("partitioner.class", 
                    "org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner");
                properties.put("request.timeout.ms", 30000);
                properties.put("timeout.ms", 30000);
                properties.put("max.in.flight.requests.per.connection", 5);
                properties.put("retry.backoff.ms", 5);

                //Instantiate Producer Object
                Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
                return producer;
```

ERROR LOG:

```
2022-05-21 14:55:21.240  WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-05-21 14:55:21.240  WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2022-05-21 14:55:22.254  WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

Comment: KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS should not have localhost. https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka#accessing-apache-kafka-with-internal-and-external-clients

Answer (score -1):

Can you try removing those quotes and double quotes in the port forwarding part
In my docker-compose file I don't use any quotes for port forwarding